# Way to display number of queries on a page? (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I used to program procedural PHP with direct MySQL queries.  So it was real easy to see what was going on in terms of hitting the DB.  Now that I'm using MVC pattern with Python on GAE, it's all a little mysterious to me :)  I generally think I know where all the DB activity is.  But I was wondering if there was a way to figure out the number of times we hit the DB (App Engine datastore) on a given page (view).  Just in case I program something the wrong way expecting 4 hits and I'm actually in some strange loops that hits it 200 times.  And I think it would just be good to have so I can get a rough idea of what's going on.

Anyone have any ideas?

p.s. I'm using Flask, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appstats. Pretty easy to setup, and you'll be able to see all major RPC calls.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Answer (score 1):

An in-line alternative that we use with a lot of success is https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler.

You can view the traceable stack and get a lot of information not visible to you with just appstats.